# How do I get the next point in a PostGIS linestring given the prior point as input

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I have PostgreSQL8.4+PostGIS.

I have a table  with linestring geometry in one column. I have one point of this linestring and i want get a next point. For this i want to use a functions [ST_NPoints](http://www.postgis.org/docs/ST_NPoints.html) and [ST_PointN](http://www.postgis.org/docs/ST_PointN.html). For use this I must sort all points find my point and after this I will know that next point it what I need.

This is my table:

```
-- Table: filedata

-- DROP TABLE filedata;

CREATE TABLE filedata
(
  num serial NOT NULL,
 id integer,
 mydata character(25),
 the_geom geometry,
 CONSTRAINT filedata_pkey PRIMARY KEY (num)
)
WITH (
OIDS=FALSE
);
ALTER TABLE filedata OWNER TO postgres;
```

And example linestring:

```
"LINESTRING(60.7014631515719 56.8441322356241,60.7023117507097 56.8445673405349,60.702948200063 56.8447993944193,60.703902874093 56.8448574076656,60.706236521722 56.8447993944193,60.7094187684889 56.8449444273664,60.7121236782406 56.8450894597515,60.715571112238 56.8452925041466,60.718382096882 56.8454085290207,60.7204505572805 56.8453505166286,60.7222538304482 56.8450314468649,60.7246405155233 56.8444513130533,60.7260194891224 56.8440742212539,60.7260194891224 56.8440742212539,60.7260194891224 56.8440742212539,60.7260194891224 56.844045214035)"
```

Comment: Sample data and schema? If you show some sample `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT`s, as well as preferably a table of expected results, it really helps with answering questions. Also, *please* put put your PostgreSQL version in questions.

Comment: Effectively you want to treat the linestring as if it were an array of points and find the point with an index one greater than an input point. Is that right? Or do you want to sort the list of points then get the next-greatest point? If you mean the next-greatest point, not the one with the next position along the list, how do you define "greatest" point?

Comment: @Clodoaldo Please don't retag with version-specific tags unless it's a question strongly related to a particular version, eg "this works on Pg 8.4 but not 9.1". This isn't. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/85744/193985

Comment: How do you sort points? They're 2-dimensional. Do you want to sort by x then y? Or do you mean "sort them into the same order that they appear in the original linestring" ?

Comment: @CraigRinger I'm not sure what you mean. I did add a version specific tag to the existent main tag. I did not delete the main tag. Is that what you call _retag_? In this question I don't know if the version is important but I added the version tag because you asked for the version so I supposed that was relevant.

Comment: @Clodoaldo I was probably just being over-pedantic. Read that meta.SO link for what I'm talking about. Basically, no need to edit a post to move version info into a tag, though if the post is very specifically about that version it's worth adding a tag if there isn't a version tag. If everything is tagged "postgresql-8.4" it's harder for someone looking for a problem specifically with postgresql 8.4 to find questions only about 8.4

Comment: Kilver, just a reminder from what I've said a few times before: If you include sample data *and expected results* it's easier to understand what you're asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you mean the next one in the linestring order, you could do something like:

```
WITH 
  -- The input data; this would be from the `filedata` table normally
  geom(line) AS (VALUES ('LINESTRING(60.7014631515719 56.8441322356241,60.7023117507097 56.8445673405349,60.702948200063 56.8447993944193,60.703902874093 56.8448574076656,60.706236521722 56.8447993944193,60.7094187684889 56.8449444273664,60.7121236782406 56.8450894597515,60.715571112238 56.8452925041466,60.718382096882 56.8454085290207,60.7204505572805 56.8453505166286,60.7222538304482 56.8450314468649,60.7246405155233 56.8444513130533,60.7260194891224 56.8440742212539,60.7260194891224 56.8440742212539,60.7260194891224 56.8440742212539,60.7260194891224 56.844045214035)'::geometry)),
  -- Create a set of (index,point) rows
  --
  point_series(line,n) AS (
      SELECT line, generate_series(1, ST_NPoints(line)) FROM geom
  ),
  -- Annotate that row set to include the prior point in each row,
  -- ie (n, point_n, point_n_minus_one)
  --
  lagged_points(pointidx, point, lagpoint) AS (
    SELECT n, ST_PointN(line,n) AS pointn,
           lag(ST_PointN(line,n)) OVER () AS point_n1
    FROM point_series
  )
-- Now SELECT the point we want, the point after
-- the one specified in the WHERE clause
SELECT astext(point)
FROM lagged_points
WHERE lagpoint = 'POINT(60.7014631515719 56.8441322356241)'::geometry;
```

This would be significantly simpler if PostGIS offered a way to convert `geometry` into an array of points. It'd also be simpler if it had an equivalent of intarray's `idx` function.

Comment: Its what i want. But i have not a point's coordinates i have a serial number for example 4 or 5 or 6.

Comment: @KliverMax Argh. Why do you say that NOW, not write a clear question in the first place, or reply to requests for clarification? The above has all the clues you need to work out how to do that for yourself; just omit the `lag()` step and use `WHERE n = input_index+1` instead.

Comment: Postgis has st_dumppoints() which can be used to get an array of points.